# Why does an object reorder itself automatically?

Tags: javascript

i have created an object with the content of points and the mark you will get with

```
marks: {
                900: 1.0,
                822: 1.1,
                804: 1.2,
                786: 1.3,
                768: 1.4,
                750: 1.5,
                732: 1.6,
                714: 1.7,
                696: 1.8,
                678: 1.9,
                660: 2.0,
                588: 2.4,
                570: 2.5,
                552: 2.6,
                534: 2.7,
                516: 2.8,
                498: 2.9,
                480: 3.0,
                462: 3.1,
                444: 3.2,
                426: 3.3,
                408: 3.4,
                390: 3.5,
                372: 3.6,
                354: 3.7,
                336: 3.8,
                318: 3.9,
                300: 4.0
            },
```

if i show the object in the console the output will be

Object { 300=4, 318=3.9, 336=3.8, more...}

you can see it live on http://jsfiddle.net/Sx4Z2/

whats wrong and why is there an order in an object?

Comment: I guess it's interpreted as an array with numeric indices. If you want to prevent ordering, try calling the elements e.g. `i318, i300` etc. (although it could be that the console always orders its properties by name)

Comment: why it is an array? mark = {} => object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMA-262 does not specify the ordering of keys in objects. Please note the following, however:

1. Almost every JavaScript engine does retain key order anyway.
2. ... unless those keys are integers, in which case they usually don't.

So, in your case, you should be able to provide predicable behavior (although not based on any standard) if you prefix your keys with some non-alpha string.

Comment: Relying on undocumented behaviour is usually a bad idea.

Comment: The behavior isn't actually "predicable".  It could change with any new version.  *Don't* rely on it!

Comment: I agree that it's probably not advisable.  However, virtually all browser vendors have recognized that there are enough sites "in the wild" that rely on this behavior such that they support it as a feature. Can't seem to find it right now, but I've even seen a bug filed against V8 for a regression here, which was subsequently fixed.

Answer (score 4):

If the order is important for you, you should use an array. You can't trust property order in JavaScript objects. In your case, I'd use something like:

```
[
    {key: 900, value: 1.0},
    {key: 822, value: 1.1},
    // ...
]
```

Take a look at this question: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Would an array with numeric indices not get ordered the same way, though?

Comment: Edited the answer to regard your question. ;)

Comment: +1 for reason & alternate

Comment: OK, this is reliable, but how would I actually access the property with the key `900` without walking through the entire array every time?

Comment: I think the only way to access directly without walking through it is to create another object to hold the respective indexes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't `reorder` itself - a JavaScript object has no specified order. If you need order, use an array.